# Matlab: Saving plot images, override plot.m

Tags: matlab, plot, overriding

Working on MATLAB 2008, I am trying to save all the images my scripts produce when invoking the "plot" function.

In order to achieve this, I have two possible solutions:

1. Either I write another function having the same parameters and perform a search/replace in the `*.m` sources
2. or I override the `plot.m` file so that I write the image into a specific directory when generated.

I did many searches and I am unable to find the `plot.m` source file. The only file I found is located in the toolbox directory and does not contain any code (except some commented documentation).

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use the `print` command and save them into a directory that you can also make using the `mkdir` command.

Sample code

```
clc; close all; clear all;
x = 1:10;
y = x.^2;
plot(x,y)
if exist('plots','dir') ~= 7
    mkdir('plots'); % make directory if it does not exist
end
print -dpdf ./plots/jawn.pdf
```

Read the print documentation, to learn how to print in other file formats

Also, I would not suggest overriding the plot command, and you will likely not be able to find the source code for plot.m because that is proprietary MATLAB code